# Finding out sigma sum notation

Tags: calculus

Hello I am trying to find values for A and B for this sigma sum problem and figured out A which turned out to be 89, so wouldnt B=45? since 4005-AB=0 and 4005/A=45?

$$1+2+3+4+\cdots+89 =\sum_{n=1}^{A} B$$

Can someone clarify? Thanks

Comment: $1+...+89=(89)(90)/2=89*45=\sum_{n=1}^{89}45$. Note you can interchange $A$ and $B$ so $\sum_{n=1}^{45}89$ is also good.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum^{A}_{B=1}B=\sum^{89}_{n=1}B=89B$$
You know that
$$\sum^n_{i=1}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
So, the sum is
$$89B=\frac{(89)(90)}{2}=89\cdot 45=89\cdot 45$$

So,
$$B=45$$
Also, if you take $B=90$, can you see what $A$ would be?